# Привязать function() к родителю, но не вызывать при нажатии на его дочерний блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня написана функция которая срабатывает при нажатии на **li.defaul** 
**(он выделен на скрине)** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он функция срабатывает так же когда нажимаю на дочерний блок **input**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Задача: не дать выполняться функции при нажатии на дочерний блок** 
Сама функция:

```js
var changeCell;
    $('.default').mousedown(function(){
        setTimeout(function() { $('#address-input').focus(); }, 100);

        changeCell = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($('#'+changeCell).children().length == 0) {
            $('#'+changeCell).append('<div></div>');
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: @uorypm я думал пойти путем e.target(), ну попробую и это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Внутри ивэнта использовал **e.target** : `if (this === e.target) ...`